# The key {'Id'} cannot be added to query type . Query types cannot have keys

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

After I upgraded my project to target .Net Framework 4.7.2 the Razor was missing. I downloaded DotNetCore 2.2. Whereupon the app quite working at runtime when the context was called.

This used to work

Comment: I removed the [Key] attribute from the POCO (s) representing the database views.

Comment: what happen then ? does error gone and works fine ?